# Codeigniter Session Lost After Redirect To ACS Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having an issue with my session data randomly being destroyed on redirect.

Application Specs:
PHP: 7.0
Codeigniter: 3.1.11

I've included a new payment system that uses 3dSecure payments (https://developer.globalpay.com/api/3d-secure), the issue randomly happens when the ACS server redirects back to the application.

The system will randomly destroy the session data and log the user out meaning the payment is not completing.

After the redirect, the process function needs to know the card details and the GI persistent object which I store in a session to be called on in the process function.

```
// Set an array of the card details to use on the 3D secure page
        $verify_data = array(
            'cardnumber' => $cardnumber,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'cardname' => $cardname,
            'cardtype' => $cardtype,
            'expdate' => $expdate,
            'exp_month' => $data['ex_month'],
            'exp_year' => $data['ex_year'],
            'ccv2' => $ccv2,
            'payment_packageid' => $pid,
            'package_code' => $pcode,
            'package_id' => $pid,
            'request_amount' => $amount,
            'order_type' => $type,
            'order_userid' => $data['user_id'],
            'merchant_id' => $orderid
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata("verify_data",$verify_data)
```

;

```
$md = $threeDSecureData->getMerchantData();
              $md->add('fee_id',$pid);
              $mdString = $md->toString();

              // We need to persist the MD object so add to the userdata for use with the verify method
              $this->session->set_userdata("MD_OBJ",$md)
```

;

Steps that replicate the issue:

1. User logs in
2. User selects package and enters card details
3. User redirected to auth server
4. Auth server redirects back to our application with the required details (issue happens here)

My session config is below

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I have read through all the other articles relating to session problems and these haven't resolved my issue, I've also checked my log files and there's nothing relating to session or drivers/libs failing to load.

I have set up a benchmark in the process function and when the session is lost it's not reaching this function as the system redirects them to login because the login session data doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: Check what `SameSite` attribute your session cookie gets set with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: I've looked via inspector and SameSite is empty